# Proof of inequality and determining convergence/divergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove that $\frac{1}{\sqrt x}\ge\frac{2}{x+1}$ for all $x\gt0$

I started by letting $\sqrt x=n$, giving me $\frac{1}{n}\ge\frac{2}{n^2+1}$, then taking the inverse and rearranging to get the quadratic $n^2-2n+1\ge0$, which when I solve it, gives me $n\ge1$ and therefore $x\ge1$. This proves that the inequality holds for all $x\ge1$, but doesn't account for when $0\lt x\lt1$? How can I account for that?

Thanks very much in advance

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2881133/divergence-convergence-of-the-infinite-series-for-frac1-sqrt2n-1-frac1/2881149#2881149

Comment: Ah, thank you, I'll delete the second part

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2883341/proving-frac1-sqrtx-ge-frac2x1-for-x-0

Comment: I've had a look at the answers to the post you linked, and they kind of just arrive at the same point as I did, that sqrt(x)>=1. But that doesn't seem sufficient to me?

Comment: $x^2-2x+1 \geqslant 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$, not just for $ x> 1 $.